# Semantic markups to index PDF files

Tags: pdf, indexing, semantic-web, schema.org

What is the proper way to index PDF files ? I would like to add semantic information in them, and help search engines present the files more accurately, more precisely (a particular image, text inside the PDF file). I am thinking about using ontologies that engines already understand like [Schema.org](http://schema.org/).

Comment: I'm not sure this answers your needs, but you might find this interesting: http://www.w3.org/TR/cooluris/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, interesting indeed. Actually, I am focused on how to add semantic markups around documents like PDF, and make these markups be indexed by search engines. Any way to use RDFa for example, as we could do on html pages?

Answer (score 3):

How about using schema.org to link to the PDF file from a web page like this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <img itemprop="thumbnailUrl" src="http://www.example.com/how_to_build_a_web_app.jpg"/>
  <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/how_to_build_a_web_app.pdf">
    <span itemprop="name">How to Build a Web App</span></a>
  by <span itemprop="author">John Smith</span>
  <div itemprop="description">This short e-book explains what a web application 
  is and how to build one.</div>
</div>
```

This lets you associate a title, image and textual description with the article in the PDF.

Comment: Ok, it encompasses the PDF to give generic information. Anyway to be more specific and point to specific locations inside the PDF with such semantics?